# How to set the value of a JSON request body to an Array instead of String

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have the ff. code that gets a value and sends a request to the API

```
this.apiService.remove(this.toRemoveItem.itemSelected).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.someProcessService.save(null);
    }, error => {
      this.someProcessService.errorScenarioFlow(error);
    }
```

And the service is here

```
export class DummyApiService {
......
  remove(Item: string) {
    const body = {
      Item
    };
    return this.http.post(this.mock, body, {
      headers: this.headerTest(localStorage.getItem('headers'))
    });
  }

  .....
}
```

What this does is that it gives me an output of

```
{
"Item" : "Selected Item" 
}
```

But what I need to have as output is

```
{
"Item" : ["Selected Item"] 
}
```

where Item is an array of items. But for some reason, it keeps on adding double  quotations to the start and end of the value of the selected items, hence making Item a String instead of an Array. How do I make it output into an Array of Items instead of String of Items.

Comment: please share source code of `headerTest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const body = {
      Item: [Item]
    };
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26168968)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the purpose but you can always destruct an object and map it:

```js
remove(Item: string) {
    const body = { Item };
    const { item, ...headers } = this.headerTest(localStorage.getItem('headers'));

    return this.http.post(this.mock, body, { headers: [item] });
}
```